# Arbitrary spaces are inserted into .idx-file and mar makeindex

Tags: indexing, xindy, imakeidx

In my MWO `teubner.sty`, no matter where and how it is loaded, makes `splitindex` insert arbitrary spaces in the `.idx`-file (see below).

It works, at least in this sample, if I replace `\index` with `\oldindex`, which is what `LetLtxMacro` is supposed to do---but doesn't actually do.

In another document of mine the `.idx`-entries with spaces are not omitted but treated in a different way than their spaceless brothers even if the content is the same.

In the sample I include all packages which I need and which may interfere with the index.

```
% Index-spaces.tex
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: xetex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,greek.polytonic]{babel}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{teubner} % <-- seems to be the troublemaker
\savesymbol{breve} % <-- used by another package
% \let\breve\relax
\usepackage[twothirds]{thinsp}
\usepackage[splitindex,xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=fpl,title={Fontes Platonici},program=xindy]
\makeindex[name=fan,title={Fontes Antiqui},program=xindy] % fontes
                              % antiqui
\usepackage[xindy]{reledmac}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\savesymbol{breve}
% \let\breve\relax
%%%------it doesn't matter at which point teubner is loaded-------
% \let\breve\relax
% \usepackage{teubner}
% teubner.sty seems to cause trouble
% \savesymbol{breve}
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\oldindex\index
\RenewDocumentCommand\index{o m}{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {\oldindex{#2}\ignorespaces}%
    {\oldindex[#1]{#2}\ignorespaces}%
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\innote{m}{#1\textit{n}}
\NewDocumentCommand\nindex{m}{\orig@@index{#1|innote}} % for
                                % compatibility with reledmac
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \section{Lorem}%
 \label{sec:Lorem}%
 \index[fpl]{Index@\emph{Inx.}!178a@178|(}% 
 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, %
 \index[fan]{Hesiod!NotIndex@\emph{NoIx.}!0116@116\,f.} 
 vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. %
 \index[fan]{Hesiod!YesIndex@\emph{YesIx.}!0120@120}% 
 Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\newpage %
\index[fpl]{OutOfIndex@\emph{OutIx}!177b@177b\,f.}% 
Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien es iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices %
 \index[fpl]{Index@\emph{Inx.}!178a@178|)}% 
 bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan 
 \newpage
 eleifend, %
 \index[fpl]{Index@\emph{Inx.}!178a@178\,a} 
 sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

 \printindex[fpl]
 \printindex[fan]
 \end{document}
```

From Index-spaces-fan.idx

```
\indexentry{Hesiod!NotIndex@\emph  {NoIx.}!0116@116\penalty \@M \hskip 0.07emf.}{1}
\indexentry{Hesiod!YesIndex@\emph  {YesIx.}!0120@120}{1}
```

Only the second entry (`!YesIndex`) appears on the pdf.

Comment: `\oldindex{\unexpanded{#2}}` and similarly for the other branch.

Comment: Is this what you mean:
    `\RenewDocumentCommand\index{o m}{
         \IfNoValueTF{#1}
       {\oldindex{\unexpanded{#2}}}
       {\oldindex[#1]{\unexpanded{#2}}}}`? Nothing changes for me.